# How to give multiple parameters in the cucumber feature file

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, footer, gherkin

Can i know how to pass multiple parameters in the feature file(cucumber)..?

eg: i need to automate the links in the footer section of a website like there are more than 14 links in the section. Which way is good to pass those multiple parameters.

please help me

Comment: using Scenario Outline you can achieve this task

Answer (score 1):

Using Secnario Outline you can pass multiple parameter.Below is the feature file example.

```
     Scenario Outline: login with valid username and password
     Given open browser
     When enter the URL "example.com"
     And Enter register username "<username>" and password "<password>"
     And Click on login button
     Then verify login

     Examples: 
     | username         | password         |
     | **************** | **********       |
     | **************** | **********       |
     | **************** | **********       |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781785286001/1/ch01lvl1sec15/sending-multiple-arguments-in-steps) to send multiple files with the cucumber feature in java.